# How to pass a function inside a directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have created `on-blur` directive for user that blurs out from the input field

```
<input type="text" on-blur="doSomething({{myObject}})">
```

myObject looks like:

```
myObject = {a : foo, b : bar ... }
```

this is how my directive currently looks like:

```
    myModule.directive('onBlur',function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope,element,attrs) {
            element.bind('blur',function(){
                console.log('blurrred');
            });

        }
    }
});
```

**How do I execute the function doSomething({{myObject}})** when the blur event is triggered?

I've tried doing something like this that has failed to work:

```
...
            element.bind('blur',function(){
                console.log('blurrred');
                doSomething(object);
            });
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside linking function you can call: `scope.doSomething()`. To evaluate expression you could do: `scope.$eval(expression)`, to get access to scope objects simply use: `scope.myObject`.

Of course this is only true for directives not working in isolation.

Answer (score 2):

You ng-blur is missing scope.$apply. It has no reference to your callback function, and you callback function needs to be defined at current scope:

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('AppController',
    [
      '$scope',
      function($scope) {
        $scope.myObject = {a: 'foo', b: 'bar'};

        $scope.doSomething = function(item){
          console.log(item);
        };
      }
    ]
  );

app.directive('ngBlur', function() {
  return function( scope, elem, attrs ) {
    elem.bind('blur', function() {
      scope.$apply(attrs.ngBlur);
    });
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="AppController">
  <input ng-blur="doSomething(myObject)" />  
</div>
```

[Working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Eizdwyi0HLJG0RzJRRqF).